# Raw JavaScript: .forEach makes request multiple times

Tags: javascript, frontend

code is below, I'm using querySelectorAll().foreach to see when any of the 'edit' buttons are clicked, the code does everything it needs to except the pwp function is asking repeatedly to the n number of edit buttons... kinda
example: there's 3 profiles with there own edit button. if you clicked the last user profile to edit, it will run the pwp function 1 time. hit the middle user profile edit button it will run 2 times, 1st user profile will make the request 3 times. thanks in advance

```
document.querySelectorAll('.editBtn').forEach(btn =>{
    //look for any edit buttons to be clicked
    btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        //figure out what profile edit button was clicked:
        var btnParent = btn.parentElement.parentElement;
        //find numerical value of the index of the parent
        var parentIndex = getChildIndex(btnParent);
        // the parent index value corelates with the users array. pull up the user:
        var current_user = users[parentIndex];
        //password prompt
        if (pwp(current_user) === true) {
            editUser(current_user);
        }
    });    
})

//prompt and ask for password
function pwp(user){
    var attempt = prompt("Provide user's case sensitive password to edit");
    console.log(attempt);
    console.log(user.password);
    if (attempt === user.password) {
        
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Wrong password entered")
        return false;
    }
}
```

tried originally running a for(let I=0; I<container.children.length; I++) and a few other times instead of the querySelectorAll().forEach(). but still didn't work.

Comment: Move this function call before the loop

Comment: The only thing I can think of is weird html that has editBtn nested inside editBtn.

Comment: Try cancelling the event object argument of the click handler (not currently declared in the code) to see if profiles have been accidentally nested inside each resulting in event processing bubbling up the  DOM and finding additional event handlers. If you require further assistance please edit the question to include just enough HTML for readers to reproduce the problem.